# .net client for AS2 EDI comunication

Tags: c#, .net, public-key-encryption, sign, edi

I have to prepare client application (c#) to send EDI messages over AS2. To be honest our client have no control over comunication and can see only correctly sended EDI messages.
I tried different solution and libraries to test it like http://www.edidev.com/example_edi_transmission.html, https://mattfrear.com/2010/07/13/send-as2-with-dotnet/ and other, but none of them does not works with customer AS2 provider. I thought that support of AS 2 provider will help me but for now it doesn't work. 
I found a test AS2 server which cover my needs to do the tests (setting are the same as  AS2 provider) but sended requests didn't shown on request list. My production requirements::

- Encrypt - 3DES with XXXX.cer
- Sign - SHA1 with YYYY.cer
- Mdm mode - synchronous
- Signed MDN - YES

So far my message which doesn't throw error (but don't work too) looks like:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Thu, 12 May 2016 09:40:14 -0060
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data; name=smime.p7m
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=smime.p7m
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Message-ID: person@company.com
AS2-Version: 1.0
AS2-To: xxxx
AS2-From: yyyyy
Disposition-Notification-To: <person@company.com>

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx signed and encrypted data xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Has anyone done this kind of comunication. Any advice, library (open source), mime params need to specify, documetation ? I lost about a week on this without any progress. I will be grateful for any help :)

Comment: The obtained quality corresponds to the price paid... Did you count the cost of your time?

Comment: Without seeing your code, there's little we can do to help.  All you're showing us is MIME headers.  Who tasked you with writing AS2 communication software when there are literally hundreds of cheap solutions out there?  This group offers one connection for free: https://www.nsoftware.com/ibiz/edi/

Comment: So, do you got answers my friend? Did you find any open source solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

I created [a project](https://github.com/chrissten/as2/tree/main/AS2Client) based on Matt Frear's [excellent blog post](https://mattfrear.com/2010/07/13/send-as2-with-dotnet/) and tested it against [OpenAS2 v3.9.1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openas2/). I hope it helps someone!